# Problems with using matlab to print text files of large column vectors

Tags: matlab, text

I have the following code in MATLAB:

```
A = [T,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O];

fileID = fopen('baseline1.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s\n','T','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O');
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s\n',A);
fclose(fileID);
```

T and B-O are all column vectors with ~1500 elements.

The point of this code is to print out these elements into a large text file that will have the list names T and B-O on the top, and list the values of each variable underneath its title (so everything that is T will end up in the T column, etc).

However, what is *happening* instead is

a) the file has the headers printed on the first line. *In addition*, 15 numbers from the data are also on that same line.

b) the file is printing 15 elements per line, as intended. *However*, it happens to actually be printing the column vectors *sideways*, cutting them off after every 15 elements and starting on a newline. It will, at the end of each list of data, cut off the list, maybe start a newline or a few, depending on its mood (there aren't a consistent number of newlines it sticks, and it will occasionally not start one at all), then start some of the data from the next list on a newline (but not enough to cover a whole row, and off center from the rest of the data), in an also inconsistent quantity. However, after the weird line, the data look normal again (relative to what the program is doing)

I have very little clue what's going on. Please send help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fprintf` accesses its data columnwise, while you print the data row-wise. Try transposing `A` in your print:

```
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s\n',A.');
```

Another problem is that you have 16 fields in your print, yet only 15 variables given to `fprintf`. You have one too many `%12s`. I suggest generating your format string with `['%6s ' repmat('%12s ',[1 14]) '\n']`.

MATLAB has the weird behaviour that if you have less input parameters than format fields, then the format string will be truncated. For instance,

```
fprintf('%d %d %d\n',[1 3]);
```

will print `[1 3]` without a newline, because it failed to reach the end of the format string. It's not at all logical, nor useful, but it's just how it works.

In your print for `A` two things collide: firstly, your 16-field format string doesn't chop up your data as you would expect it to, and even then it reads the data columnwise from `A`, i.e. first every value from `T`, then every value from `B`, etc.

So, bottom line is that I would rather do this:

```
A = [T,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O];

fileID = fopen('baseline1.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,['%6s ' repmat('%12s ',[1 14]) '\n'],'T','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O');
fprintf(fileID,['%6s ' repmat('%12s ',[1 14]) '\n'],A.');
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: That *kinda* made progress. Now the data is in the right orientation, but the first few rows are all kinds of screwy. After that, the data has a correct orientation and *looks* like a table, but T and B are stuck on the right of the columns relative to everything else. Also, one of the lists apparently starts with a bunch of "d"s? I don't know why. (If it helps, these column vectors were generated by ode15s: and yes, the diff eq solver needs to be stiff)

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics, please confirm that 1. you use the exact code above, and 2. that your `A` is of size `[N, 15]`. Come to think of it: isn't `A` a numeric array? Then `%12s` will not be a proper field specifier...

Comment: 1. The only thing I changed for the code is the names of the lists/list headings (the lists aren't actually name B and D and G and stuff).

2. A is [N, 15], and it is a numeric array except for those weird "d"s.

Comment: Replacing 12s with 12f pretty much fixed the problem. There's some weird formatting--the columns are off center from their headers-- (And T appears to have its first and last numbers truncated for some reason), but for the most part, it looks good. Is there anything I can do to fix the truncation issue?

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics I'm not sure about what you mean about "truncated". '%12f' will use some floating-point format, you might want to be more specific. Either something like `%12.8f` (leading to "  0.12345678" or something) '%12.8e' (leading to "0.12345678E+00" or something; note that this won't fit 12 characters). The latter, exponential format might be better if your numbers can be small: "0.12345E-05" is preferable to "0.00000123" and is more precise.

Comment: The first and last numbers of T just don't get inserted into the big data thing. It just puts spaces there as though they're *supposed* to be there, but they aren't. And thanks for the E advice!

Comment: Never mind. Fixed it. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics No problem, glad I could help:)